# How can I set graph.set-vertex-id=true when running JanusGraph using the official Docker images?

Tags: docker, janusgraph

I am running JanusGraph using the official Docker image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph

For my graph, I need to be able to set my own IDs for nodes and edges, and this can only be done when `graph.set-vertex-id=true` is set in the JanusGraph configuration. I am able to open the shell in the Docker container and edit the config file to include this option, but for it to take effect I believe I need to restart the graph, which I am not sure how to do from within the Docker container.

I believe I have two options, neither of which I know how to do or if they are possible:

1. Launch the Docker image and edit the config file in the container as I have done, and then somehow restart the graph without restarting the container.
2. Somehow launch the Docker image with the config already editied so that JanusGraph launches with `graph.set-vertex-id=true` already set.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could do it according to the project's git hub page.

1. You could overwrite properties by setting environment variables as described [here](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker#configuration).
2. You could mount the property file point to your local file as described [here](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker#mounted-configuration).

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.